# I can't see overlay top content

Tags: html, css

I can't see overlay top content. In above top content have overlay title. I try set various styles from stack overflow but it didn't work. Please look into this.

In HTML

```html
<div class="overlay-content-wrapper">
    <div class="overlay-content">
        /*............*/
    </div>
</div>
```

In CSS

```css
.overlay-content-wrapper {
    display: none;
    position: fixed;
    z-index: 9;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
    overflow-y: auto;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

.overlay-content {
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    background-color: #fff;
    padding: 0 40px;
    border-radius: 10px;
    width: 900px;
    margin: auto 0;
}
```

Please look at this image - [image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this.

And if you wanna leave some space in content's top, modify `top` value as you want.

```css
.overlay-content {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, 0);
  /* ... */
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you don't restrict the height of `.overlay-content`, it can get greater than 100%, and with being centered it is impossible to see the upper-most and lower-most part of it.

You can try setting `max-height: 100%` to it, perhaps with `overflow: auto` to make a scrollbar appear if necessary.